# Remove Video Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to remove the video progress bar for this video player? I need this to be part of the video embed code I share with others.

```
<iframe id="hapyak-player-157199-8825" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" src="//www.hapyak.com/embed?key=ce7faab838a547faad26&amp;project=268988&amp;native_controls=false" width="720" height="442" class="hapyak-embed hapyak-responsive"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is not a code question, this is just an iframe loading someone else's 3rd party app

Comment: The code you posted is for an `<iframe>`, not a `<video>` element. Scripts on your webpage _may_ be able to manipulate the actual `<video>` element in the loaded iframe document, but script security policy may prevent that.

Comment: I got you. I've been told there is paid subscription level for the video hosting that allows me to hide the timeline. I was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to remove the timeline to prevent people from seeking, or are you trying to get rid of the dots that HapYak places on the timeline when you have an interaction? If you're just trying to get rid of the HapYak added dots, try changing the URL parameter of your iframe source to "native_controls=true"

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I'm trying to remove the timeline to prevent people from seeking.  I'll try your suggestion to see the results anyway. Or, I wouldn't mind removing the player gui altogether.